# Images from PDF to presentation: low quality

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-office, pdf, screen-capture

I have a PDF that has some embedded images, and for some reason I'm not able to extract them with wondershare PDF editor (they're not even seen as images). So I tried to make a screenshot with cmd+alt+4 but the captured images have a too low quality, specially when I insert them into a powerpoint presentation. This is how they are seen in the PDF:  [image]

And this is how they appear in the presentation: [image]

I don't know if you can see the difference, but it's clearer when I run the presentation on my macbook. The problem is that I don't find a way to directly extract the images, so I'm looking for an alternative solution, something like a high-quality screenshot or another way to extract images from the PDF.

Comment: What method did you use ?

Comment: To extract the images I used wondershare PDF editor, and there was only was inside it. I discovered that all the other elements are excel objects but an image is still missing.

Comment: Sorry, why would you need the wondershare? Can you give me the link to the pdf online so I can test.

Comment: I download the pdf and then open it in Preview, from there I can extract elements. I assume you have the try-it version of wondershare?

Comment: Yes I'm using the free version, this is the link: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/wsdm13-threads.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview app on 10.6.8 doesn't let you extract images except by selecting then copying and creating a new file from clipboard.

Another way is using the free unix xpdf tools. They come with a utility called `pdfimages`. I just used it on a PDF and it perfectly extracted the images from the file.

For example...

`pdfimages -f 2 -l 2 -j 27487.pdf testname`

It extracted the images starting (-f) and ending (-l) on page 2 and saved as JPG.

xpdf is available from HomeBrew.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Extract images and graphics directly with a free app: [The Unarchiver (App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) ; The Unarchiver is mostly used/known for compressing and uncompressing files.

Just right-click and `Open With` > `The Unarchiver.app`

Or simply drag the file directly to The Unarchiver

[image]

Works fine with pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pot, pps, pptx, and others.